# Reactjs: Difficulty in applying CSS even after increasing Specificity

Tags: css, reactjs, styling

I have a particular piece of code in a component which is as follows:

```
return (
    <div className="Home" id="Home">
      <Customnav color="" height="80px" padding="5vh"/>  
    <div className="parent">
      <div class="col-5 son"> 
        <span id="codeflow-text" className="codeflow-text">Codeflow</span>
        <span style={{color:"black", fontSize:"70px", fontFamily: "Arial"}}><b>Learning</b></span>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-7 daughter"> 
        <img src={img1} alt="loading"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Now I have imported Home.css in this js file part of which is as follows:

```
div#Home span.codeflow-text {
  color: "#1cbdd6" !important;
  font-size: "70px";
  font-family: "Raleway";
}
```

Now according to me, the word "Codeflow" should import the attributes which I defined but it's not working. On Inspecting I am getting this in the browser:

[image]

I tried to increase the specificity and I know the rule of using !important. But something seems to be wrong here. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, the value of property should not be wrapped within `"`(Except some special case). Change your Home.css file as follow

```
div#Home span.codeflow-text {
  color: #1cbdd6 !important;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: Raleway;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add "" between color and font-size. Just remove them.